# JavaScript - replace substring using a variable

Tags: javascript

```
var prefix = 'pre-',
    number = 1,
    combined = prefix + number,
    prefixRemoved = combined.replace('/' + prefix + '/g', '');
console.debug(prefixRemoved);
```

How do I remove `prefix` from `combined`? I'm still getting `pre-1` as a result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you pass a variable to a Regular Expression JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass a string to `replace()` like this:

```
prefixRemoved = combined.replace(prefix, '');
```

or if you need parameters on the regular expression, you can create a regexp from a string like this:

```
prefixRemoved = combined.replace(new RegExp(prefix, "g"), '');
```

or, you can create the regex object first:

```
var re = new RegExp(prefix, "g");
prefixRemoved = combined.replace(re, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the [**RegExp**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) object:

```
var prefix = 'pre-',
    number = 1,
    combined = prefix + number,
    prefixRemoved = combined.replace(new RegExp(prefix, 'g'), '');
console.debug(prefixRemoved);
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/nYaKg/)

---

Why that is happening:

```
// this syntax without quotes is shorthand for creating a RegExp object
typeof /aaaa/; // object
/a/ instanceof RegExp; // true

// since String.replace can take a string or a RegExp, it has to assume that any string is just a string 
typeof "/aaaa/"; // string
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex for this. Simply use the string as is:

```
var prefix = 'pre-',
    number = 1,
    combined = prefix + number,
    prefixRemoved = combined.replace(prefix, '');
console.debug(prefixRemoved);
```

Comment: +1, but I guess, techically it can be simplified to `console.log(number)`

Comment: there is a difference between /prefix/g and prefix, one replaces one match, the other replaces all matches. In this instance it might not be an issue, but the general question is how to use a variable within a RegEx.

Comment: @zzzzBov - I was simply trying to help the OP solve his problem. A lot of people jump first to regex when they have a problem. But really, that should be the last tool you use, after everything else in your toolkit has failed you...

Comment: a global variable replace is *very* common. I'd rather have people understand how to make a simple RegEx to do what they need rather than avoid RegEx out of fear of the unknown.

Comment: @zzzzBov - He specifically asked to remove a prefix, and the best way to do that is the way I've shown him...

Comment: @zzzzBov, ease up on the hate for those that offered an *alternative* solution. While I agree there is nothing to *fear* with Regular Expressions, they are a specific tool with a specific purpose. Obviously there are several of us that think this is not a good use of that tool.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no need for using regular expressions since you are merely performing string replacement.

```
prefixRemoved = combined.replace(prefix, '');
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/jjYC8/

Comment: this is incorrect, it will only replace the first occurrence of `prefix`. Using `/prefix/g` will replace all occurrences.

Comment: True. But look at the example code: `pre-1`. So there's no need for the global replacement. Thanks for the down vote though.

Comment: +1 there is no need to vote this down @zzzzBov.  The OP never said he needed to replace more than one instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need `prefixRemoved = combined.replace(prefix, '');`

```
var prefix = 'pre-',
    number = 1,
    combined = prefix + number,
    prefixRemoved = combined.replace(prefix, '');
console.debug(prefixRemoved);
```

Just call the variable directly.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jaffc/